# How to manage GUIDs offline

Tags: security, synchronization, offline, guid

Given that [clients can tamper with GUIDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript#comment17936032_2117523) if they are generated client-side, wondering how to mitigate this problem if you allow working offline.

Say you have a Todo list application and are working offline. From what I'm thinking, as you create todos, the client is creating GUIDs for the todos, as well as any attachments or associated records. Then say you go back online and it syncs. The GUIDs created on the client could have been tampered with, so something possibly needs to happen during a merge. Maybe all new GUIDs are created server-side, and sent back to the client to overwrite the client-generated ones. Not sure.

Wondering what best-practice is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think yes, ids could be reassigned when sent to the server. One way this could be done is have a client-side id and a server-side id, the latter only assigned if it's saved. The client-side id can then also be removed from the design, but then upon a succesful save all references must be updated.

And then the problem is the inevitable inconsistency, because what happens if the server already received the update, assigned a server-side id, but the confirmation response never made it back to the client. Upon the next download, the client will see a new item on the server which it cannot associate with any client-side item, unless there is some kind of a heuristic to identify duplicates (eg. if all fields are the same in a client item without a server-side id, it is most probably the same).

I think this is less of a security question though, if the format of the id is validated (for example it must be a guid, ie. numbers, letters and dashes), it doesn't really matter what exactly the client sends. So from a security point of view, this is almost purely an input validation question, which of course must be in place, errors must be thrown on already existing ids and so on. Then it touches on access control as well, if multiple users are using the app, but that's a different topic, any access must be authorized anyway, and access control decisions must not be made solely on the id. That is, it's not a good access control model if you can access anything you know the id of.